# I am trying to send data from my flutter application to my local api made with django

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework

here you can see views.py,

[image]

models.py

[image]

and url.py
[image]

and you can see here my flutter postdata function with static values
[image]

when i call my function it's dont work and it's return status.code error 400

[image]

but when i try to post data using postmant it's work

[image]

Comment: from what i am seeing on postman you are sending formdata  try to remove jsonEncode from your flutter and try again

Comment: Why do you have that trailing / in your route urls?